# Which are the most Promising Post-quantum Public Crypto Primitives in the Face of a Quantum Apocalypse?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto

I'm fairly new to the fundamentals of post-quantum cryptography.  So, please forgive me for such a direct question.  Searching Google opened up a whole lot of amazing ideas that are thought to be quantum-safe, and there were many confident submissions made to NIST.  I've heard of SIDH, lattice-based cryptography, etc.

But all of these seem overwhelming and exciting for a beginner.

Can anyone please suggest to me some resources that start from scratch for learning about the underlying fundamentals of these primitives?

For me, our present-day crypto primitives like RSA, ECC, etc., were very easy to learn and are very intuitive because of a whole plethora of information available on the Internet.

Before we ever thought of the disastrous effect of quantum computers on our present-day public-key cryptosystems, we had a lot of confidence in our public key algorithms (I'm not referring to implementations). Even now (at the time of writing this) we are thought to be safe from quantum attacks. But considering the amount of investment and resources on quantum computing, I feel that these algorithms should be kept ready, in software, so that we are well-prepared for a "Quantum Apocalypse".  As far as symmetric ciphers are concerned, we will have to just **increase** the key size. The only known attack is Grover's search algorithm, which accelerates the brute force search of an encryption key. But the countermeasure to increase the key size from 128 bits to 256 bits is sufficient. But we are unable to find such an easy one for our present public-key crypto primitives.

So, again, which are the most promising post-quantum public crypto primitives that can be used with confidence in the face of a "Quantum Apocalypse"?

Comment: By "promising", what do you mean?  The ones which we have the most confidence in?  The ones that look to be the most practical when we consider implementation considerations?

Comment: @poncho Yes, the ones that we have confidence in, and are practical!

Comment: It may be most appropriate to make this question a community wiki question, and have a different answer for each of the candidate hardness assumptions. If you're looking for a single hardness assumption to focus on based on "having the most confidence in and best performance", it seems premature to suggest one before the competition is over. That being said, a different question of "which PQ cryptosystem is the easiest for a novice cryptographer to learn about" seems interesting.